# 日本語に違和感：バッジ　市民パトロールの説明

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「初めて通報された投稿」ではなく、「初めて投稿を通報をした」ではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。次回のビルドで提案の文書が適用される予定です。

Comment: @jmac 「初めて投稿を通報をした」はまだ日本語として違和感がありますね。「初めて投稿を通報した」が良いと思います。

Comment: @tomute 訂正しました。

Comment: @jmac ありがとうございます。